# Is Reform conversion recognized by the Conservative movement?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, heterodox, reform-judaism, conservative-judaism

Are people who have converted to Reform Judaism recognized as Jews by the Conservative movement?

Comment: To VTCers: We’ve discussed this before on Meta, but sometimes people need a reminder. Questions about Reform and Conservative Judaism are on-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this *teshuvah*](https://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/sites/default/files/public/halakhah/teshuvot/20012004/16.pdf) by R. David Novak, adopted by the Rabbinical Assembly in 1982.

To quote from its conclusion (emphases mine):

> **I find no cogent basis in halakhah for accepting, even ex post facto,
>   converts who did not undergo specific *tevilah* for the sake of conversion**,
>   unless it can be shown that they are strictly observant Jews, particularly
>   scrupulous in the use of a mikvah. The fact that they may have been taken
>   to be Jews by themselves or by others does not change the need for tevilah
>   for the sake of conversion. The fact that most of these conversions have
>   been conducted under Reform auspices makes the matter especially difficult
>   because of the cordial relationships which exist between Conservative and
>   Reform rabbis and lay people. Nevertheless, this halakhic requirement is
>   not meant as a public rebuff to the Reform movement. **If a Reform rabbi
>   conducts *giyyur kehalakhah*, I accept his converts as bona fide Jews.**

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.